# Linked list class

Tags: c++, arrays, list, class, hyperlink

The purpose of my program is to read in data from a file and build a linked list with this data and then deallocate all the nodes used.

the program also needs to print out the address of nodes after they are created and  then after that they are deleted

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <fstream>

  #include "BigHero.h"

 using namespace std;

 // Linked List Struct
 struct Node{
    BigHero data;
    Node* Next;

    };

  // Funtion Prototypes
  int countHeros(string,int&);
  void createList(BigHero,int,Node*&,Node*&,Node*&);
  void printList(Node*,Node*,Node*);
  void deallocateList(Node*&,Node*&,Node*&);

  int main()
 {
      // Program Variables
      Node* head;
      Node* currentPtr;
      Node* newNodePtr;

     string Filename = "ola5party.dat"; // File string varible
     int charNumber = 0; // variable to hold number of Heroes
     int i = 0; // Loop control varible


    countHeros(Filename,charNumber); // Function call used to count number of   Heros

     ifstream inFile;
     inFile.open(Filename.c_str());
     if(!inFile){
     cout << "Error in opening file" << endl;
     return 0;
     }

      BigHero Hero;
     while(inFile)
       {
          inFile >> Hero;
          createList(Hero,charNumber,head,currentPtr,newNodePtr);
       }

    printList(head,currentPtr,newNodePtr);

    deallocateList(head,currentPtr,newNodePtr);




    inFile.close();

    return 0;



}

  int countHeros(string Filename,int& charNumber)
  {
     ifstream inFile;
     inFile.open(Filename.c_str());
     string aLineStr;
     while (getline(inFile, aLineStr))
         {
           if (!aLineStr.empty())
           charNumber++;
         }

          inFile.close();
          return charNumber;
     }

    void createList(BigHero Hero, int charNumber,Node*& head, Node*& currentPtr, Node*& newNodePtr)
    {


         head = new Node;
         head->data =Hero;
         currentPtr = head;

         newNodePtr = new Node;
         cout << "Allocated # " << newNodePtr << endl;
         newNodePtr->data = Hero;
         currentPtr->Next = newNodePtr;
         currentPtr = newNodePtr;




        }

         void printList(Node* head, Node* currentPtr, Node* newNodePtr)
         {
                if(head != NULL)
                {
                  currentPtr = head;

                    while(currentPtr->Next != NULL)
                    {
                       cout << currentPtr->data << endl;
                        currentPtr = currentPtr->Next;
         }

      }

    }

       void deallocateList(Node*& head ,Node*& currentPtr,Node*& newNodePtr)
       {
            if( head != NULL)
             {
                currentPtr = head;
                while( head -> Next != NULL)
                {

                    head = head->Next;
                    cout << "Deleting # " << head << endl;
                    delete currentPtr;
                    currentPtr = head;


             }
             delete head;

             head = NULL;
             currentPtr = NULL;


            }
       }
```

the program like this runs without errors, but here is the problem it will input all the information required but since i only have one variable hero class it is constantly replacing the information.

i tried to make a class array (example hero[i]) but cant seem to get it right and am not even sure if that is the solution. Everything is fine but i cant get the desired number of class object and i always end up with one class

this is my desired output but i only get one class object

```
     Allocated#0x8722178
     Allocated#0x87221d0
     Allocated#0x8722210
     Allocated#0x8722230
     Allocated#0x8722288
     Allocated#0x87222c8
     Hero:MacWarrior­Level134,(34,16,48)­Exp:13425
     Hero:LinuxMage­Level149,(24,54,21)­Exp:14926
     Hero:PCBard­Level122,(18,32,17)­Exp:12221
     Hero:PythonThief­Level90,(24,18,61)­Exp:9001
     Hero:CplusPaladin­Level159,(31,38,29)­Exp:15925
     Deleting#0x8722178
     Deleting#0x87221d0
     Deleting#0x8722210
     Deleting#0x8722230
     Deleting#0x8722288
     Deleting#0x87222c8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have misunderstood the basic idea behind a link listed. You are not supposed to overwrite `head` again and again when adding element. `head` shall only be changed when the list is empty.

Try something like this:

```
struct Node
{
    BigHero data;
    Node* next;
};


void addNewNode(Node*& head, ....)
{
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        // List empty so add new node as head
        head = new Node;
        head->next = nullptr;
        return;
    }

    // Find last element in list (performance can be improved with a tail*)
    Node* temp = head;
    while (temp->next != nullptr) temp = temp->next;

    // Add new element to end of list
    temp->next = new Node;
    temp->next->next = nullptr

    return;        
}

int main()
{
    Node* head = nullptr;

    addNewNode(head, ....);

    return 0;
}
```

For performance it is often good to have a tail-pointer also.

Further you should not define `head` in `main()` but make a class/struct for it and put the relevant functions in the class. Like:

```
struct Node
{
    BigHero data;
    Node* next;
};

class ListOfNode
{
    public:
    ListOfNode() : head(nullptr), size(0) {}

    ~ListOfNode()
    {
        // Delete all nodes
    }


    void addNewNode(....)
    {
        // ....

        ++size;
    }

    size_t size() { return size; }

    private:
    Node* head;  // Optional: Add a tail* for better performance
    size_t size;
};

int main()
{
    ListOfNode list;

    list.addNewNode(....);

    cout << list.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```